# Javascript to update contact entity

Tags: javascript

I have two fields in contact entity named Last Appointment Date and Next Appointment Date.
I want to populate this field with values from the appointment entity when new appointment is created.
When i create an appointment i will select a contact name the related contact should be update with the values in the appointment fields.
can any one help??

Comment: You really should provide some more context and informations... maybe some code too.

Comment: Are you asking about java or javascript? Please remove one of the tags accordingly.

Comment: What is a contact entity and why is there a Java and a JavaScript tag?!?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see from your profile that you're new here. The more detail you can provide in your question, the better. Is the question about Java or JavaScript? (Or is it really both, which seems unlikely?) Are you using a framework of some kind (JEE, CRM, etc.)? People will try to help, but you'll get better help more quickly if you can give more detail.

Comment: Voted to close as a duplicate of your newer [JavaScript to update values in MSCRM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110639/javascript-to-update-values-in-mscrm) question, even though this question predates it, since the newer one is clearer. That's probably backward, though, kinda wish I'd gone the other way now.

Answer (score 0):

What part are you having problems with?

It sounds like you should be able to use standard variable assignment to do this.  If appointments must *always* have a contact, you could perhaps do this in the appointment's constructor:

```
function Appointment(contact)
{
   ...
   contact.nextAppointmentDate = this.date;
}
```

otherwise, you could do this in the code that creates the appointment:

```
Appointment appointment = new Appointment(date);
contact.nextAppointmentDate = appointment.date;
```

I'm not really sure whether you're asking about best practices here in general, or about the specific wiring, or if there's an additional complexity that you haven't mentioned.  Is there a reason why you can't simply update the fields?

Comment: i am using CRM in that i want this action to happen.
I want to use java script in onsave event of the form

Comment: You may want to manually copy this answer to his newer version of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110639/javascript-to-update-values-in-mscrm  I don't know which one will get closed.